# Python debuggers not working after updating PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pudb

I experiencing the the following error when I attempt to use pudb and the PyCharm debuggers. I was recently updated PyCharm and thereafter I'm experiencing this failure. Here is a example of the how I'm attempting to start the process: python3.4 -m pubd.run initdata.py

Here is my Pycharm info:

PyCharm Community Edition 2016.1.3
Build #PC-145.971, built on May 3, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_40-release-b132 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

```
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 15, in <module>
    import importlib.util
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/importlib/util.py", line 12, in <module>
    from contextlib import contextmanager
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 4, in <module>
    from collections import deque
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/collections/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from keyword import iskeyword as _iskeyword
ImportError: cannot import name 'iskeyword'
```

Comment: This import statement is interesting I can not find the collection module in the following direcotry /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/ from collections import deque

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to having a file called keyword.py in my script directory. Found the answer here.

[Import urllib or urllib 2 in Python 2.7 failing with ImportError: cannot import name iskeyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086634/import-urllib-or-urllib-2-in-python-2-7-failing-with-importerror-cannot-import)